# ¿De dónde viene el nombre de "roque" para la torre del ajedrez? ¿Cuándo se usó esa denominación?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, juegos

En el juego del ajedrez existe un movimiento especial llamado *enroque*, en el cual se permite al rey desplazarse dos casillas en dirección a la torre, y situar esta al otro lado del rey.

El caso es que acabo de averiguar que en inglés a este movimiento se le denomina *castling*, de *castle* 'castillo', el nombre de la pieza.

¿Entonces nosotros por qué no decimos *entorrar* o algo así? Pues resulta que al parecer el nombre antiguo de la pieza era:

> **[roque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Whh3Pql)**
>
> Del ár. hisp. *rúẖẖ*, este del ár. clás. *ruẖẖ*, este del persa *roẖẖ*, y este del pelvi *rah* 'carro de guerra'.
>
> 1. m. Torre del ajedrez.

Pero si antiguamente el nombre de *roque* designaba a un carro, ¿por qué se usó para la torre del ajedrez? ¿Cuándo se usó *roque* y cuándo se cambió por *torre*?

Comment: Lol llamamos castling sí, pero la palabra más típica es *rook*, no *castle*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Varias de las piezas del ajedrez han cambiado varias veces de nombre a lo largo del tiempo. Parece ser que, en efecto, el nombre antiguo de la pieza era, en todas las lenguas europeas, un derivado de una palabra que significaba "carro de guerra" en alguna lengua oriental (y que llegó a Occidente a través del árabe). De hecho también lo es (o es de nuevo) en inglés: la torre se llama *rook*, siendo *castle* una forma anticuada.

El origen del cambio fue nada menos que un poema escrito en 1527 por [Marco Girolamo Vida](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Girolamo_Vida). El poema se llama *[Scacchia Ludus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%AFssa#Vida%27s_poem)* ("Juego del ajedrez"), pero se lo conoce por el nombre de su protagonista, una dríade griega llamada Caissa, inventada por Vida, que es la musa del ajedrez. Al buscar nombres latinos para las piezas, Vida se rehusó a usar los términos medievales (como *rochus*), y describió las torres así:

> *Tum geminae velut extremis in cornibus arces
>
> hinc atque hinc altis stant propugnacula muris,
>
> quae dorso immanes gestant in bella Elephanti.*
>
> Y luego gemelas, como en los extremos, bastiones en las esquinas,
> aquí y allá se yerguen defensas de altas paredes,
> que son llevadas a la guerra a espaldas de inmensos elefantes.

(Traduzco de una traducción, no encontré nada mejor.)

[image]

Así el carro de guerra parece haberse transformado en un castillo o torre móvil transportada por un elefante en su lomo (pensemos en la memorable escena de la batalla en Ithilien en El Señor de los Anillos). Nótese que la palabra "torre" no aparece en la escena, pero el contexto la sugiere. Un bastión o una ciudadela fortificada bien puede ser una torre y ambas cosas son parte prominente de un castillo. La palabra latina es *arces* (*[arx](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/arx)* = "bastión, fortaleza, defensa").

En el resto del poema se usa la palabra "elefante" para referirse a la pieza, y así se la llamó durante un tiempo además de "torre" o "castillo".

No he podido determinar en qué fecha se produzco el cambio en castellano, pero el Diccionario de Autoridades, en 1737, sigue diciendo *[roque](http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getdoc&DocId=69140&Index=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CDA_INDEX&HitCount=1&hits=1%20&SearchForm=%2FDA_form%2Ehtml)*, y así siguen nombrando a la pieza los diccionarios de la Real Academia hasta 1869 inclusive.

[image: RAE 1869]

En las ediciones posteriores del Diccionario *roque* continúa apareciendo, pero a partir de ese momento se dirige al lector a la palabra *torre*.

[image: RAE 1884]

Todo esto parte de lo explicado por H. J. R. Murray en *[A History of Chess](https://archive.org/details/AHistoryOfChess/page/n827)* (1913), del cual dejo aquí un recorte de la parte relevante.

[image: A History of Chess p. 827]